# Create a very large absence/presence SPARSEE matrix in Python

Tags: python

Is there any magic way to create an huge absence presence matrix in python? **pd.crosstab and pd.pivot_table fail** because of the memory requirement.

I have an extremely large dataset like this one:

| Person | Thing |
| --- | --- |
| Peter | bike |
| Peter | car |
| Jenny | bike |
| Jenny | plane |

and need this:

|  | Bike | car | plane |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Jenny | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Note, the matrix is rather sparse. It contains a lot of zeros.

Comment: But seriously, how much data do you have, and what is the RAM available?

Comment: 10'968'174 rows and 8'739 cols. Standard_E16_v3 on Azure

Comment: If you do not mind with using `dask`, it is great package to handle large datasets, and similar with `pandas`.  Also, there is function `.pivot_table` in `dask`. For more information, you can visit https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Computers used in data science sometimes have absurdly high amount of RAM (I think I've seen one with 1tb before...)

If you don't have that much RAM, then I think the only way to resolve this is to utilize the hard drive...

I would say, process the data, write it as a structured data on to a hard drive, and loop through while reading, say 50mb at a time to check if the name has already been added to the file, and modify it.

Comment: Thanks, this is what we are doing, but I thought there might be some algorithm that would do memory inefficient cross tab. I could not find it anywhere though so I guess what you propose is the way to go.

Comment: One thing i might do is possibly compress the data as much as i could by making a JSON file containing a dictionary of numbers to the names, and then representing  the data in bytes (or bits)

Comment: What if I tell you that the matrix is sparse. Would there be any method for a sparse matrix that saves memory?

Comment: In that case, i think one way to resolve that is to write an algorithm encoding the number of zeros. For example, 1 0 0 0 3 0 0 3 2 0 0, can possibly be recorded as 1 3 3 2 3 0 2 0 2 (where the numbers at even indices represent the number of zeros in between?) This might work if there are especially many zeros in a row. (You can be as creative as you can ofc)